# how to create font-size for html email on iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone, font-size

I'm trying to create an email that will display the same number of spaces horizontally on a iphone 5 and and iphone 6.  Is there anyway to do that with proportional fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to look into using viewport units like `vw`. These use a percentage of viewport width or height. However, this may not be supported in the email client used by the user.

**CSS:**

```
h3 {
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```